# How to execute Powerpoint on a remote computer using psexec

Tags: psexec

I have a remote computer I'd like to launch a powerpoint presentation remotely using psexec.  I would like the powerpoint presentation to launch on the REMOTE computer.

I'm trying to execute the following command and it says "invalid file name"  I have verified the file exists

psexec -u domain\user -p password \remotepc -h C:\Test\Test.pptx

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
psexec \\remotepc -u domain\user -p password -h -i C:\Test\Test.pptx
```

Notice you have 2! slashes before the remotepc name.
And I added the -i option.